# Release Java web application scoped static resources

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a application scoped static resource that I will initialize it at the time ServletContext initialized.

Here is my code:

```
    public class StaticResource {
        private static Map<Class, MyBean> staticMap = new HashMap<>();

        public static void add(Class clazz, MyBean b) { ... }
        public static MyBean get(Class clazz) { ... }
    }
```

StaticResource will be packaged into a MyJar.jar and this jar is put into myWebApp/WEB-INF /lib.  I add this information to let us know StaticResource is ONLY for my application ( Not shared)

The code I initialize like below:

```
    @WebListener
    public class AppListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        StaticResource.put ( Bean1.class, myBean_instance1);
        StaticResource.put ( Bean2.class, myBean_instance2);
            // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // --- Do I need to set NULL to StaticResource.staticMap?
    }
```

MyBean class is very simple, just contains some properties with types Class, Primitives, Method, ...

MY QUESTION is in contextDestroyed function, do I have to set NULL to StaticResource.staticMap?

As my understanding, staticMap will be destroyed when the StaticResource class unloaded (After the contextDestroyed executed), so setting NULL to staticMap is NOT NEEDED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to, unless your java code is bundled in a jar which is on your application server libs.

When undeploying your application, your application server will discard the `ClassLoader` which is assigned to your webapp. But if your code is in the server libs directory, then it will be loaded by the application server `ClassLoader` and therefore it will not be garbage collected.